How can I run Spatialite in XAMPP
I have downloaded the files from https://www.gaia-gis.it/gaia-sins/windows-bin-amd64/ and moved the dll files to C:\\xampp\apache\bin and added extension=mod_spatialite.dll to the php.ini file.  This should be a simple installation however I receive the following error.
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Can't load module 'C:\\xampp\\php\\ext\\mod_spatialite.dll' as it's linked with 2.30, but the core is linked with 14.29 in Unknown on line 0

It appears they are using a really old version to compile these files.  What can be done to remedy this issue?

See Gaia-SINS for more information. This comment is meant for the readers of your question.
